# choosing the right pattern for object composite

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring, uml, facade

There is a class named "Bill". 
Bill can be either "Electricity" , "Food" or "Customer" which are all POJO.
So it contains three objects:

```
    public class Bill{
      private Electricity el1;
      private Food el2;
      private Customer el3;
      //setters and getters
      public setElectricity(...)
      ...
    }
```

List of Bills are populated using some DTOs.
And each time, I need to check all elements to be sure what type of bill am I having.

My goal is to refactor this design.

I could also have one object and set the content regarding to the type, but is it having any standard pattern?

Is there any pattern for classes who can be a class based on the type that is requested?
I mean Bill will be either electricity, food or customer regarding to the populating time.

Note: My application favored composition over inheritance
      It is also a “design by contract” based application.

> Edit:
>   Bill is not an abstract of it's objects. 
>   Lets assume, food is just specification of food like color and receipt!
>   A bill can be one and only one of the object at a point of time.

Comment: `ElectricityBill`, `FoodBill`, `GasBill`. What different fields do each have?

Comment: You've shown us something about the composition of your classes, but not the behavior.  Does each bill behave the same, e.g., chargeCustomer(), or differently e.g., electric.turnOffPower(), gas.shutoffValve(), food.lockStore()?

Comment: Infact they are having many differences, what I made is just an example of my real code , but to make it more cleare assume that Bill also have a customer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ElectricityBill, FoodBill, GasBill has some common functionality, then create Bill as abstract class and extend other classes from bill.

If they have altogether different behaviour and state (which i doubt)then create Bill as interface and let other concrete class implement them.

i usually call it simple factory pattern(dont confuse it with factory method/abstract factory pattern)

```
public class BillFactory
{
    Bill createBill(String type)
    {
         if(type.equals("Electricity"))
           {
            bill=new ElectricityBill();
       }
        ........


    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any standard Pattern to apply for that? At least can mention that a pattern applied?

Comment: Its basically PTI i.e Program to an interface.

Comment: Any pattern for a class that can be one of few objects at a point of time?

Comment: Appreciated and voted up your answer, but still didn't get what I am looking for. Is there any pattern for classes who can be a class based on the type that is requested? I mean Bill will be either electricity, food or customer regarding to the populating time.

Answer (score 2):

Bill is an abstract entity hence it should be an `abstract` class. All other type of bills should extend from it such as : `ElectricityBill`, `FoodBill`, `GasBill` etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to apply a pattern. some more, they are different. Bill is not an abstract or interface of other objects that it can be. The focus is it can be one and only one of 3 different objects

Answer (score 1):

As you have a big object with many parameters out of which some can be optional.

You can use [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) for creating the instance of your `Bill` class.

> Unlike the abstract factory pattern and the factory method pattern
>   whose intention is to enable polymorphism, the intention of the
>   builder pattern is to find a solution to the telescoping constructor
>   anti-pattern. The telescoping constructor anti-pattern occurs when the
>   increase of object constructor parameter combination leads to an
>   exponential list of constructors. Instead of using numerous
>   constructors, the builder pattern uses another object, a builder, that
>   receives each initialization parameter step by step and then returns
>   the resulting constructed object at once.

Suppose you are building a house:

```
public House getHouse() {
    return this.houseBuilder.getHouse();
  }

  public void constructHouse() {
    this.houseBuilder.buildBasement();
    this.houseBuilder.buildStructure();
    this.houseBuilder.bulidRoof();
    this.houseBuilder.buildInterior();
  }
```

Example from [Java Papers](http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/builder-pattern/)

Answer (score 0):

If Bill only can contain one instace, why dont u use a interface?

```
    public interface Billable {

        double getPrize();
    }

    public class Electricity implements Billable {

        @Override
        public double getPrize() {
            return 20.0;
        }
    }

    public class Bill {

        /**
         * Billable to bill.
         */
        Billable billable;
        /*
         * Discount percent applied to bill.
         */
        @Min(0)
        @Max(100)
        double discount;
        /**
         * VAT percent applied to bill.
         */
        @Min(0)
        @Max(100)
        double vat;

        public Bill(@NotNull Billable billable) {
            this.billable = billable;
            discount = 10.0;
            vat = 21.0;
        }


        public double getFinalPrize() {
            double discountFactor = 1 - discount / 100;
            double vatFactor = 1 + vat / 100;
            return billable.getPrize() * discountFactor * vatFactor;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Electricity electricity = new Electricity();
            Bill electricityBill = new Bill(electricity);
            System.out.println(electricityBill.getFinalPrize());

        }
    }
```